# Set Theory and groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is the set $S=\{0\}$ over operation "addition" a finite group?
If yes then why not set $S^{'}=\{1\}$ over addition is a group?

Comment: Do you know the axioms of a group?

Comment: It depends on what operation you define: if we suppose they are both groups, then they are trivially isomorphic. Actually, if you define an arbitrary operation on S', then it is a group (prove it). Nevertheless with respect to addition (the one defined in $\mathbb Z$) S' is not an algebraic structure (it is not closed).

Comment: because $1+1=2\notin S'$.

Comment: It depends on how you define addition.

Comment: Any one-element set can be given a group structure in a unique way. Whether this is compatible in some sense with other properties of the one element depends on what those properties are.

Answer (score 3):

Given that $S$ is in bijection with $S',$ the two objects are identical in terms of their properties of being a set. If you define any map $$m:S\times S \longrightarrow S,$$
then this map (binary relation) will have to give $m(0,0)=0.$ Similarly  If you define any map then this map will have to take $m(0,0)=0.$  $$m:S'\times S' \longrightarrow S',$$
then this map will have to give $m(1,1)=1.$ That is, any **binary relation** defined on a singleton set will produce what is called the trivial group.

Answer (score 1):

A group has to have an identity, and it has to be closed under the operation. If we re-define addition to make $1$ an identity, so that $1+1=1$ then $G=\left(\{1\},+\right)$ could be a group, but it would probably confuse a lot of people. We generally use $0$ as the additive identity.

If you choose multiplication for your operation, then $G=\left(\{1\},\cdot\right)$ makes a perfectly good, one-element group, which nobody would complain about.

Comment: Yes I know about groups and I know { 1} is not group over addition as 1+1=2 doesn't belongs to set so set is not closed...but I wanna ask how we take 1+1 as set  {1} has cardinality 1 so it has only one element so how we can take two elements 1 and 1

Comment: A binary operation doesn't require two *distinct* elements. If there's only one element present, you use it twice. Formally, addition maps from $G\times G\to G$, and if the set $G=\{1\}$, then $(1,1)\in G\times G$.

Comment: Thanks sir that is what I was not aware of and thus confused...thanks a lot